# Grant access to select from one table, but not access to underlying tables?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to create a view of a large accounts database and give access to this view to a specific user. However, I don't want that user to be able to access the underlying database and tables.

So, a view called 'db1.dbo.myview' which contains 'select acctid, onstop from accounts.dbo.customers'. Allow the user to select from db1.dbo.myview, but not anything from the 'accounts' database.

Is this possible?

From searching on the web it seems I need to create a stored procedure, sign it with a certificate, create users from the certificate, etc. A whole nightmare.

Answer (score 1):

You should just be able to do this:

```
grant select on dbo.myview to myuser
```

Comment: I tried that and it complained 'The server principal "user" is not able to access the database "accounts" under the current security context.'

Comment: Do you have a server login connected to a database user?

Comment: Yes, like I said, 'user' can access the database 'db1', but doesn't have any rights to access the database 'accounts' which the view depends on. I was wondering if it was possible for the view to assume the rights of the owner of the view (who does have access to 'accounts') rather than the rights of the user of the view (who doesn't)

Comment: You can do this with cross database ownership chaining - here is a pretty good article: http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1782/understanding-cross-database-ownership-chaining-in-sql-server/